# How is it possible for the application to throw a redeclaration error on deleted and unexisting function?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I declared getLesediSimilarPropertyOnShow() function. When I run the application, I get this error below:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
GautengPropertyDB::getLesediSimilarPropertyOnShow() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\ajax-live-search\libs\GautengPropertyDB.php on line 4704
```

I deleted this entire function thinking about the duplication. 
 But when I tried to check if the function **getLesediSimilarPropertyOnShow()** exists by pressing CTRL+F, The Find and Replace Dialog Box displays **Not Found in the current document.** Meaning the function does not exist. But when I tried to reload the page, the same message persits and the line 4704 is located on comment lines outside of all functions that has nothing to do with the code. I thought may be it was previous error loaded in the cache memory and I cleaned the cache but the same error stands still. But the function does not exist in the file. I don't understand this phenomenon. Can someone  please explain this?

Comment: It's probably in another file that is being included somewhere along the line. Or you are not editing the file you think you are compared the one being used on the page in question.

Comment: The file is obviously used in another application but the function itself does not exist in the file at all. That's why I'm wondering how can this error happen.

Comment: You're right Dave. I double checked and I eventually created different file to be uploaded in the live server. When I got the first error message, I deleted the function in that file forgetting that other file holds the same error. I was keeping running the old file instead. Reason why I kept on receiving the error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At first use IDE like PHPStorm, that show for you where function declared.
Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php for check if function already declared